# Determine center of bins when using meshm

Tags: mapping, latitude-longitude, matlab

I am using `meshm` to plot densities. 
**How do I calculate the center point for each of the bins? I want to associate the data in m with the centerpoints** I have looked at the source code of `meshm` and believe the solution will be a modified version of `meshm` that returns the latitude and longitudes of each bin's center point.

`meshm` calls the function `meshgrat` which returns the latitude and longitude points of the mesh that will be plotted by `surfacem`. The problem is that the lat and lon matrices are not the same size as m. **I need to match the latitude and longitude points with the density data in m** I believe I need to scale the data based on GRATSIZE a variable in `meshgrat`.

NOTE: [meshm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/map/ref/meshm.html) is part of the Matlab Mapping Toolbox

NOTE NOTE: This is a follow-up question to [Determine distance from coastline in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576169/determine-distance-from-coastline-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within `meshm` just modify the inputs to `meshgrat`:

```
[lat,lon] = meshgrat(Z, R, gratsize); % original 
[lat, lon] = meshgrat(Z,R); % modification
```

By default, `gratsize = []` which in meshgrat will return the default graticule size of 50 X 100. By not passing in gratsize, the graticule is set to the same size as Z.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the edges of the mesh using [MESHGRAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R13sp2/toolbox/map/meshgrat.html), which is the function called by `meshm` when it makes the grid for binning.

```
%# create the mesh that is used by meshm
[latgrat,longrat] = meshgrat(m,termaplegend);
%# find the latitudes of the center points
latPts = (latgrat(1:end-1,1:end-1) + latgrat(2:end,1:end-1))/2;
%# find the longitudes of the center points
lonPts = (longrat(1:end-1,1:end-1) + longrat(1:end-1,2:end))/2;
```

The center of the bin in 2nd row, 5th col is `[latPts(2,5),lonPts(2,5)]`.

Comment: In the above example, latPts and lonPts are <49 X 99> double matrices. I want to match the center points to the data in m